# Error: The app failed to resume properly from snapped view

Tags: c#, window, windows-store-apps

I want to submit my app on windows store but due to one error I can't.

Error:

> Content compliance: failed
>
> The app failed to resume properly from snapped view.

How to sort out this error? I have [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx) but not able to get proper solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your app fluidly adapts to the snapped view. Perhaps that is why it failed.

> If you keep the default minimum width of 500 pixels, you do not have
>   to make any special considerations for your app at narrow widths. You
>   simply design your app so that it adapts fluidly when the user resizes
>   the app

Comment: dude can u explain me from the scratch, i am not able to get it .

Answer (score 0):

One should keep provisions for snap view in UI.
Its in UX Guideline of store app.
if its not supported then appropriate view should generated for the same

[This Link will helpfull to you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/12/10/walkthrough-implementing-snapview-in-your-windows-8-app.aspx)